# What does it mean when a %CPU exceeds (# of cores) x 100%?

Tags: macos, safari, performance, activity-monitor

Several responses to a question [I asked earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/36845/internet-kiosk-for-motel-lobby) suggested I try Opera kiosk mode, so I decided to download it and give it a try. Once the download had completed and the disk image was being verified, Safari hung for over a minute and there were periods where Safari used a very high %CPU:

[image]

In Mac OS X 10.5, I was accustomed to seeing Safari freeze, but it never used up more than 200% CPU (2 cores x 100%). Is this a bug in Activity Monitor? Or does this mean that %CPU is now more akin to [system load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29)?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Do you see high numbers when the program is NOT marked "`Not Responding`"?

Comment: Yeah, this was the only time I saw it. I actually went as high as 3,000% for a second, but the system was barely responsive so it was difficult to get a screenshot.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The % CPU is relative to 1 core, so 726% is using almost 8 cores. Core is loosely defined, so 1 [Hyper-Threaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), "virtual" core looks like 2 cores to Activity Monitor.

What type of system do you have? If it is just 2 cores (which is seems to be) then nik's answer sounds correct.

A late model 8-core system can look like 16 cores to Activity Monitor:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's a 2-year-old MacBook - 1 processor, 2 cores. So... probably a bug.

Comment: If the CPU is a two core, a 700% CPU usage is a bug :)